# Create connected data in neo4j at runtime with volume of 10-20 million nodes per day

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

In my java application ,I am reading  events from kafka and inserting it as nodes in neo4j db. I am expecting approx 10-15 million nodes per day.

Nodes main properties are *EVENT{uniqueId, id1, id2, id3, id4, eventTime, other-properties...}*

Just after inserting 1 batch of nodes (200 events per batch, which takes approx 150ms), I call a cypher query to create relationship based on these ids with any of the matching EVENT from past 1 day.
One event can be connected to many event.

All ids are in format of UUIDS and I have created unique constraint for *uniqueId* and index on *id1, id2, id3 id4* and *eventTime*

My sample query (for id1) look like following where *uniqueIdList* is  unique ids of current batch event:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(" 'MATCH (c:EVENT) WHERE c.uniqueId IN {uniqueIdList} with c " + 
" MATCH (p:EVENT) WHERE p.eventTime > (timestamp() - 86400000 ) AND (p.id1 = c.id1) return p,c "+
" '," + 
" 'MERGE (p)-[:RELATED_TO]-(c) ',"+
" {batchSize:1000, parallel:false, params:{ uniqueIdList:{uniqueIdList} } })
```

I tried above query without *apoc.periodic.iterate* but with no significant change in performance.

Also since my data becomes stale in 60 days so everyday I run a cypher query using apoc.periodic.commit to delete all nodes and relationship which are older than 60 days.

I am using neo4j 3.2.6 in server mode. In my testing , I am only able to process approx 2 million EVENTs per day. Is there any way I can improve performance?

Following is EXPLAIN output of query [Explain Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tECgj.png)

Comment: I'm not clear on below:  1. Are you loading 10-20 million nodes in 200 batches per day and it takes 150 ms?  
2. Is the query executed right after node creation completes and tries to link the freshly loaded nodes to rest of the nodes existing in DB? 
3. What does the below condition means: p.eventTime > (timestamp() - 86400000 )? (timestamp() - 86400000 ) seems to return a timestamp of appx 2 years back.
4. What is the time taken to run the query and how did you calculated that appx 2 m nodes are getting processed everyday?  
5. Did you tried profiling the query to find the bottleneck?

Comment: I think your query can benefit from having an index on uniqueId as you are filtering on it in the first part of the query.  You should also try Neo4j's native Java API. 
In my experience, it's much faster than the cypher queries. If my understanding is correct, you can probably iterate over uniqueId list, find your node,n1, find all other nodes,n2 where n1.uniqueId<>n2.uniqueId and n1.id1=n2.id1. Then connect n1 to all n2 nodes.

Comment: Do you know haow many `MATCH` do you have for one Event with this query :`MATCH (p:EVENT) WHERE p.eventTime > (timestamp() - 86400000 ) AND (p.id1 = c.id1) return p,c` ?

Comment: @logisima the data is very dynamic in nature, so  this query can match in range of 0 to 10000 but usually its matches  5 to 20

Comment: @Rahul  I have updated question with more clarity on batch size.  Regarding time diff 86400000 is equivalent to 24*60*60*1000 ie 1 day. Also you can see the uniqueId already have unique constraint on it which is nothing but index with with uniqueness guarantee. So average time to insert 1 batch (200 nodes) and creation of relationship of these node with last 1 day nodes takes 10-20 sec. So with this speed I can only process approx 2 million nodes.

Comment: Have you done some configuration on Neo4j ? Do you have a good hard drive ? What is the sizing of your machine ?

Comment: My bad, I wrongly referred to the epoch time stamp. So, in simple terms, you want to match and connect the 200 nodes, say, created right now, with all the nodes created since last 24 hours, is that right? Are you matching on all ids (id1, id2, id3, id4) every time you create 200 nodes? If yes, then in a single query or multiple? Did you profiled your query? Share the profile output. Why are you using merge in 3rd part of your query? I believe you will be creating only new relationships every time unless you are matching on more than one id. Also, do give native java API a try, it's much faster

Comment: @Rahul, yes I am matching on all id id1,id2,id3,id4 but in separate query for each.  If I am not wrong native java API is only for embedded neo4j. As mentioned I use Neo4j in server mode , as there are some other application which read from Neo4j database. I will try to profile my query as well. Yes think I can replace MERGE to CREATE in my scenario , I will give it a try.

Comment: @logisima on my test environment, I am using 4 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 0 @ 2.70GHz. With 150GB SSD and 8GB RAM machine.  I did not change any default config in neo4j except allowing APOC procedure.  Also my current DB contains 56 million nodes and 100 million relationships. Database folder size is now approx 56GB.  Since i am deleting old data (older than 30 days) as well, and as per my knowledge in neo4j community edition do not reclaim/reuse space , could it affect the performance?

Comment: You can use native Java API with standalone server as well. Just write an unmanaged extension and put inside the ${Neo4j_Home}/plugins directory. Are each of queries taking 10-20 sec to execute or all of them combined?

Comment: So you will have a lot of free space in your files, this should affect the page cache mecanism. Moreover you  must configure the heap size and the pagecache of Neo4j. Do you have something else running on your server ? if not : heap -> 2 or 3g, pagecache -> 3 or 4g. Moreover can you give the explain of the MATCH query ?

Comment: yes @Rahul, 10-20 sec for 4 query (1 query each for id1,id2,id3,id4) combined. I will take a look into unmanaged extension.

Comment: @logisima So after reading 200 events from kafka i insert them into neo4j. Then I run above mentioned query. So first MATCH get all the newly inserted nodes (ie. 200 nodes) and then second MATCH get past 1 day events where events id1 is same as id1 of above match. So if above condition satisfied then I create a relationship between them. I run this query 4 times( ie. 1 for each id property id1,id2,id3,id4). So basically I am preparing a trail for connected events via any one of the ids (ie. id1,id2,id3,id4)

Comment: ot a text explaination, but the explain of the query :)  Can you add the word `EXPLAIN` at the top of the query in the browser and share with us the picture ?

Comment: @logisima Oh my bad. I am attaching explain query picture